# why does "not equal" with "or" doesn't working in c# (check if number is binary)?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, binary

I really don't why it doesn't working. **(it should check if number is binary)**
why the operators doesn't apply right?

```
using System;
class MainClass
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Console.WriteLine(IsBin(100));
        Console.WriteLine(IsBin(10011012));
        Console.WriteLine(IsBin(10911010));

    }

    public static bool IsBin(long num)
    {
        while (num > 0)
        {
            if ((num % 10) != 1 || (num % 10) != 0)
            {
                return false;
            }
            num /= 10;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to use && not || as you want to check that the last digit is not 0 _AND_ is not 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Too Long, Won't Read: Use `&&` instead of `||` in your if statement.

And for those, who wants to know why:

OR operator(`||`) returns `true` when at least one side is `true`. `So 100%10=0` and `0!=1` is true so the whole or statement will return true and program will jump into your if statement.

AND operator(`&&`) returns`true` **only** when **both** sides are `true`. `0!=1` is true but `0!=0` is false so the && operator will return false and your if will not be executed.

Is it clear?

Answer (score 2):

At least one expression on each side of the `||` is always true. So the result of the expression using `||` is always true.

You can do your check in one expression using a `!` (not), but this will make your code less readable, so I suggest store the result in a temporary variable to improve readability.

You could be using:

```
var isZeroOrOne = (num % 10) == 1 || (num % 10) == 0)
if (!isZeroOrOne) 
{
     return false;
}
num /= 10;
```